# Generalised solution to edit a json for SCIM apis using the attributes and excludedAttributes

Tags: java, json, gson, jsonpath, scim

Below is the original response:

```js
{
    "emails": [
        {
            "type": "work",
            "value": "bjensen@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "id": "2819c223-7f76-453a-919d-413861904646",
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "work",
            "value": "555-555-8377"
        },
        {
            "type": "business",
            "value": "555-555-8377"
        }
    ],
    "schemas": [
        "urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"
    ],
    "userName": "bjensen"
}
```

And in the above response I would pass `excludedAttributes=phoneNumbers.type` and the response should be like below:

```js
{
    "emails": [
        {
            "type": "work",
            "value": "bjensen@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "id": "2819c223-7f76-453a-919d-413861904646",
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "value": "555-555-8377"
        },
        {
            "value": "555-555-8377"
        }
    ],
    "schemas": [
        "urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"
    ],
    "userName": "bjensen"
}
```

Comment: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/reports/grid?attributes=phoneNumbers.type
should yield me my desired result by sending multiple values (comma separated) as query parameters.

Comment: Example:
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/reports/grid?attributes=phoneNumbers.type,phoneNumbers.value
OR
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/reports/grid?excludedAttributes=phoneNumbers.type

Comment: Sorry, but it looks like a please-do-the-job-for-me question. What have you tried so far to accomplish the result?

Comment: i have been able to do the 'attribute' part yet using jsonPath wildcard expression $..['last_element_of the_dot_seperated_string']...which eventually returned me the values only (not the keys)...
Else that i have tried to solve it programmatically using recursive methods...but couldnt make it generalised.....
I am looking out if some existing library is there which provide solutions, just like jsonPath as I could attain some part of my requirement using that.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv.....any leads?